# Enabling a disabled tab

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITabBar` containing 5 tabs. I disabled one of the tabs like this:

```
tabBar.items?[3].isEnabled = false
```

To enable it again, I am using the following code:

```
tabBar.items?[3].isEnabled = true
```

The problem is that it doesn't actually get enabled again. I also tried to place the above code inside `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, but the tab stays disabled.

Here's the full code:

```
import UIKit

class MainTabViewController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabBar.items?[0].title = NSLocalizedString("tab1", comment: "-")
    tabBar.items?[1].title = NSLocalizedString("tab2", comment: "-")
    tabBar.items?[2].title = NSLocalizedString("tab3", comment: "-")
    tabBar.items?[3].title = NSLocalizedString("tab4", comment: "-")
    tabBar.items?[4].title = NSLocalizedString("tab5", comment: "-")

    self.tabBar.items?[3].isEnabled = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

}

}
```

Comment: Can you please share more of your code?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri just posted the full class code

Answer (score 0):

It should be the `tabBar` property of the `UITabBarController`.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].isEnabled = false
```

If you call it from inside the custom `UITabBarController` subclass:

```
self.tabBar.items?[3].isEnabled = false
```

Make sure `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` of the custom `UITabBarController` subclass are called only once, unlike the methods in every tab, since they are called every time the tab is selected.

The below code seems to work fine:

```
self.tabBar.items?[3].isEnabled = false

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {

   self.tabBar.items?[3].isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: this not working .. its the same .. tab[3] is still disabled!

Comment: and where you disable  it  ??

Comment: i tried just to comment the line where isEnabled=false and tried isEnabled=true but none of these worked ..

Comment: if you can check my post please .. i posted the full class

Comment: did you assigned the class in ib

Comment: yes i did ... its really weird cause when i did isEnabled = false .. worked and now i want to do isEnabled = true .. and its never working!

Comment: copy code in answer in viewDidLoad , it will disable the 3rd tab for 3 secs and re-enable it again